# MSGraph Get List Items

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am using MS Graph to get SharePoint (online) List items.

This is my code:

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
               {
                   new QueryOption("expand", "fields(select=CRItemIDNintex, CRChangeTitle, CRCategory, CRTechnicalArea, CRStatus)"),
                   new QueryOption("filter", "startswith(fields/CRStatus, '60') or startswith(fields/CRStatus, '70')")
               };

var resultListsItems = await graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId]
                    .Lists[listId]
                    .Items
                    .Request(queryOptions)
                    .GetAsync();
```

There problem is I Don't get any values for "CRTechnicalArea".
This is example off the result:
[image]

AS you can see there is no "CRTechnicalArea".

How can this be?

Answer (score 0):

I made a change and now I get all the data that I need.

```
var resultListsItems = await graphServiceClient.Sites[siteId]
                    .Lists[listId]
                    .Items[id]
                    .Request(queryOptions)
                    .GetAsync();
```